# An updater name is wrong at VSTS pull request

Tags: git, ssh, tfs, azure-devops

I have a weird issue. When I commit changes to VSTS repository it displays the update on behalf of another user, yet commits are displayed on behalf of me:

[image]

I thought maybe I use an SSH key from another user, but in my user account I have my own created SSH key that I used to copy the repository.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you are using SSH? Maybe through VTST you are using HTTPs, which can cache the wrong credentials.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue and what're steps to reproduce?

Comment: @VonC, you are right! To copy the repo I used HTTPs! Can it be the issue and what should I do now?

Comment: Check the value of git config credential.helper: if it is manager, open the Windows Credential Manager. I will add an answer later (after work)

Comment: @VonC another my colleague tried the same, but she copied using SSH indeed. And she is also commits updates under a wrong name. Probably the one she used before she got her account.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba OK. What is the value of `git config credential.helper`?

Comment: Note! what you see in GitHub are commit authors. Https or SSH does not matter: only git config user.name/user.email.

Comment: @VonC, should I execute this command in git bash? It returns only one string "manager". Seems I do something wrong.)

Comment: No, you should check your git config -l: is user.name/user.email correctly set when you do a git commit?

Comment: @VonC thanks for explanation. Yes, the credentials are correct.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba my point is, for any commit done with the "wrong author", it means the user.email was incorrect when that commit was done.

Comment: @VonC but the commiter name is correct, the updater name is wrong. Look at my screenshot in the post.)

Comment: Is it possible that your colleague has rebased (replayed) those commits, becoming a committer (even though you remain the author)? As for those Denys commits in gray, check the associated email: I bet it is not your own GitHub account email.

Comment: How do you push the commits to VSTS? According to the screenshot, the commit author is your but the owner is not which means that the changes are committed by you but pushed by others.

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT the thing is that a long time ago I didn't have my personal account at VSTS and I used someone's else accounts to work with it. Then when I got my account at VSTS I logged in with it and I use it. As I told I even re-cloned the repository being logged in with my own account. How do I push commits? Using Git Extensions utility for Windows. With my generated SSH that is added to my VSTS account.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba Before you get your account, did you use SSH or HTTPS?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT before I get it I used HTTPS to clone the repository and SSH to push changes.

Comment: Did you remove the SSH key before use the new one? And when you clone with HTTPS, did you enter the credential manually or use Git Credential Manager?

Comment: I fixed the problem, yet I don't know why it was so weird. How I fixed it: the issue is I selected to use Putty instead of Open SSH but I guess that somehow it didn't see the key I created as I didn't selected implicitly where to search for it. As soon as I selected Open SSH and renamed my key to the default name all worked well.